Embeds (YouTube, Spotify) Work Live but Won't Load in Block Editor
My site went through a few hosting updates recently and everything seems to be working fine now, except for one annoying thing: When I edit a post with YouTube or Spotify embedded blocks in it, they don't show up in the Editor. There's just a loading animation that never finishes or throws any errors.

If I look at the post preview or publish it, the embeds all work fine on the front end.
I've tried disabling all my plugins and that didn't fix anything. This is a fresh WordPress core install as of yesterday. My theme doesn't modify my wp-admin area in any notable way. Please help?

I fixed my own issue by clearing my browser cache. (Ugh. It's always the simplest thing that I miss.)

I'm glad to hear you found a solution. If possible, please come back in a couple days—I think it's 48 hours—and mark your answer as Accepted, which might help someone else having the same problem.
